# Relacionamento ActiveRecord PHP

Tags: php, orm, active-record

Tenho duas tabelas, *pedidos* e *meio_pagamento* na tabela `pedidos` tenho a *foreign key* `meio_pagamento_id`, como defino o relacionamento delas através do `activerecord` php?

**Tentei**:

### Classe MeioPagamento

```
class MeioPagamento extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $table_name = 'meio_pagamento';
    static $has_many = array(
        array('pedido', 'class_name' => 'Pedido', 'foreign_key' => 'meio_pagamento_id')        
    );
}
```

### Classe Pedido

```
class Pedido extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('pagamento'),
        array('empresa'),
        array('meio_pagamento', 'class_name' => 'MeioPagamento', 'foreign_key' => 'meio_pagamento_id')
    );

    static $has_many = array(
        array(
            'itens', 
            'class_name' => 'Item', 
            'foreign_key' => 'pedido_id', 
            'primary_key' => 'id'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Esse ActiveRecord é de algum framework:?

Comment: É o ActiveRecord PHP. Esqueci de informar.

Comment: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/